# What would happen to a non-Force-sensitive when they enter a Kyber crystal cave?

Tags: star-wars, kyber-crystal

We have many occurrences of Padawans and Jedi going through crystal caves like the one on the planet [Ilum](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Crystal_Cave_(Ilum)), to harvest their own Kyber crystals. It induces visions, hallucinations and trials for the Jedi to pass.

What would happen if a non-Force sensitive would enter these caves?

Comment: Their head explodes

Comment: Nothing I guess. non-Force sensitive Sith have entered the caves. As long as you're able to overcome your fears, you can pass without harm

Comment: Force-sensitive walks in to the cave - has hallucinations, trials, and mind-blowing experiences to get past. 

Non-Force-sensitive walks in to the cave - "oooo look at all the pretty crystals!"

Comment: AFAIR (Clone Wars), use of Force is required to open such locations. The same happens when someone tries to enter a Jedi/Sith Temple. So the caves would not open for those not Force sensitive, or, at least, they would not be able to reach the Crystals, as this requires use of Force again

Comment: @Shreedhar "non-Force sensitive Sith"?

Answer (score 3):

### Apparently nothing

#### Canon

In *Jedi: Fallen Order*, one section of the game takes place in the crystal caves on Ilum. The level's enemies are completely normal stormtroopers, who don't seem to have any reaction to the location:

[image: Screenshot of Jedi: Fallen Order showing Cal Kestis fighting a scout trooper]
(source: [gamepressure.com](https://guides.gamepressure.com/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order/guide.asp?ID=52627))

#### Legends

*Knights of the Old Republic* I and II have a crystal cave near the Jedi Enclave on Dantooine, which the player's non-Force-sensitive companions can enter with no apparent reaction:

[image: Screenshot of Knights of the Old Republic's crystal cave]
(source: [kotorguide.blogspot.com](http://kotorguide.blogspot.com/2009/06/kotor-where-can-i-find.html))